# multiple matches using file's startswith

Tags: python, regex

I have a program that takes an input a list of numbers ( comma separated ) and I am supposed to run through the the files that start with those numbers

```
myprogram.py 1,6,8
```

have to go through files that are `1001_filename, 1004_filename, 6001_filename, 8003_filename, 8004_filename` etc.,

one way is to iterate through 3 times( once for 1*, 6*, 8* ) and do if

```
for file_type in file_types:
    file.startswith(file_type):
```

but how can I match for any in the list ?

Is there a regex that can do something like :

`file.startswith(any of file_types):`  file_types here is `1,6,8`  or something to that effect ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) to find all your files:

```
from glob import glob
path = "path_to/"
files = glob(path+"[1,5,8]*")
```

We will match any file starting with `1`, `5` or `8` in whatever directory `path` points to.

Comment: @Victor Looks like `glob` uses [`fnmatch.filter`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fnmatch.py), which eventually has for loops in it. Not that it matters that much, IMO...

Comment: iam getting empty array for : print glob(path+"[1]*") eventhough i have files that match 1*

Comment: @heltonbiker i believe the system libraries loops must be much more optimized than me am just leaving it to the system.

Comment: @Victor, forca single digit you just need `1*`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex here. I suggest the usage of plain [`str.startswith` with a `tuple` of accepted prefixes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) (`tuple` `prefix` accepted since Python 2.5) while iterating over your files. Here's a small demo:

```
>>> start_list = ('1', '6', '8')
>>> file_list = ['1001_filename', '1004_filename', '0000_filename']
>>> for filename in file_list:
...     if filename.startswith(start_list):
...         print(filename)
... 
1001_filename
1004_filename
```

Comment: @heltonbiker I think that depends on what you want to do when a name matches. I you want to print it, map would be little ugly, right?

Comment: you are still using a for loop I wanted to avoid that : if any(filename.startswith(start) for start in start_list):

Comment: @Victor The way I understood your question you wanted to avoid iterating three times.

Comment: Well, I was thinking something along `if any(map(str.startswith...`, but the need to pass an argument to mapped function defeats the purpose (would need to use a lambda), so nevermind...

Comment: @timgeb: You don't even need `any`. The `prefix` argument can be a `tuple` of strings to check. So change to `start_list = ('1', '6', '8')` and make the check `if filename.startswith(start_list):` and Python does the `any` work for you, and more efficiently/succinctly to boot.

Comment: @ShadowRanger awesome, feel free to edit this improvement in.

Answer (score 1):

For the record I agree that this isn't a regex necessary question, but I do love regex so here's how to do it with regex

```
from re import findall, escape

start_list = ['1', '6', '8']
file_list = ['1001_filename', '1004_filename', '0000_filename']

print findall(r'^(%s)' % escape('|'.join(start_list)), file_list)
```

way over the top, shouldn't really format regex unless done so very explicitly, all round bad answer. I just like regex

EDIT: Added in re.escape so as to not run into too many problems

Comment: Well I appreciate the compliment, I still find it overkill but then again I guess it depends how large the volume of data you're dealing with. Also probably should add in an `re.escape` so no one tries to find files starting with `"."` and ends up with everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension based on timgeb's answer.

```
start_list = ['1', '6', '8']
file_list = ['1001_filename', '1004_filename', '0000_filename']
c = [filename for filename in file_list if any(filename.startswith(start) for start in start_list)]
```